# Ember.js : Remove row from datatable component after delete

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatable

I have a component that contains a Datatable, this component send an action 
'deleteItem' to the Controller in order to delete a specific item by its Id.

The problem is that when I delete an Item from the store the view isn't updated, So my question is how can I refresh the Datatable and show the updated data after a Delete ?

Controller.js

```
deleteItem(id){
   var store = this.get("store");
   store.findRecord('foo', id, {backgroundReload: false}).then(function(foo){

                  foo.deleteRecord();
                  foo.save().then(
                    () => {
                      console.log(`Done !`);
                    },

                    (err) => {
                      console.log(err);
                    })}
```

// foo-component.hbs

```
{{yield}}
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Decription</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.category}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

//foo-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didInsertElement() {

    this.$('table').DataTable({
      dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
      language: {
        search: '<span>Filter:</span> _INPUT_',
        lengthMenu: '<span>Show:</span> _MENU_',
        manualRowMove: true,
        paginate: {
          'first': 'First',
          'last': 'Last',
          'next': '→',
          'previous': '←'
        }
      }
    });

    this.$('select').select2({
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      width: 'auto'
    });
  },

  actions: {
     deleteItem: function(id) {
      this.sendAction("deleteItem", id);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is your datatable ??

Comment: Please check my post's update.

Comment: I'm not sure. Just check once like this. Assign this in a variable,like, var myDataTable = this.$('table').DataTable({...Then after delete row call like this myDataTable.ajax.reload();

Comment: Dosen't work for me, my source data isn't Ajax, I'm populating the DT with a model

Answer (score 2):

Once you render an HTML there is no way it will update automatically. So as long as your change does not trigger the component to reflect changes that would not happen. There was one time when I had to solve similar problem, and if I understood you correct. There is [refresh](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method in your route you can invoke after you have updated the store. This would cause the models in your route to be reloaded calling `beforeModel()`, `model()` and `afterModel()` hooks. So when you update the data store, you can use `sendAction()` hook to trigger such change, just remember if you cant call `refresh()` from any of actions, call a method outside of `actions` object and invoke `this.refresh()` there.

That shoud work if you are passing data from route without any changes into the controller and eventually to the component, or directly from route to component. However if there are operations you perform in your route before sending the data to this component, the only way to reflect such changes is to update data you pass to controller after executing such operations. For instance like this `this.controller.set('fooList', fooList);`. This should update the component if there are any changes in the data received, and will also call all of component life-cycle hooks that get invoked on re-render.

**Edited**

In your case you have to set new values to the controller

```
deleteItem(id){
   var store = this.get("store");
const self = this;
   store.findRecord('foo', id, {backgroundReload: false}).then(function(foo){

                  foo.deleteRecord();
                  foo.save().then(
                    () => {
                      console.log(`Done !`);
                      self.refresh();
                      // here you would update the values for your controller if refresh() does not help you
                    },

                    (err) => {
                      console.log(err);
                    })}
```

If you could provide code for `model` hook and `setUpController` in your rout if you have, it would be easier to explain.

At the least you should understand that updating `model` or the controller attributes will trigger updates on components that rely on those values.

Comment: None of your suggestions works for me :-/. Thanks for the reply. I'm still looking to resolve this.

Comment: Suppose you passed on data `dataArray: [1, 2, 3]` to your component via the controller.
Setting `dataArray: [1, 4, 7]`, attribute of your controller should reload the component.
If the table is drawn using javascript, you may have to redraw it with new value to reflect the update.

I'll add up snippet from you question in the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, self.refresh(); throw an error (refresh is not a function),I tried this.get('target.router').refresh(); but it does nothing after table.draw();

Comment: Can you post code in your route. Or create a twiddle [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/)